# remove cloudflare render block javascript

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I used cloudflare to protect my site, but it looks like cloudflare add a block render javascript as below:

http://www.keronsoft.com/cdn-cgi/apps/head/W1j6BzG7xAyKGShjmxldmxxxxxx.js

> ;window.CloudflareApps=window.Eager=window.CloudflareApps||window.Eager||{};window.CloudflareApps=window.CloudflareApps||{};CloudflareApps.siteId="83fd88898f7208a330f4b1ce76xxxxxx";CloudflareApps.installs=CloudflareApps.installs||{};;(function(){CloudflareApps.internal=CloudflareApps.internal||{};var
>   errors=[];CloudflareApps.internal.placementErrors=errors;var
>   errorHashes={} var noteError=function(options){var
>   hash=options.selector+'::'+options.type+'::'+(options.installId||'');if(errorHashes[hash])
>   return;errorHashes[hash]=true;errors.push(options);} var
>   initializedSelectors={};var
>   currentInit=false;CloudflareApps.internal.markSelectors=function(){if(!currentInit){check();currentInit=true;setTimeout(function(){currentInit=false;});}}
>   var check=function(){var
>   installs=window.CloudflareApps.installs;for(var installId in
>   installs){if(!installs.hasOwnProperty(installId)) continue;var
>   selectors=installs[installId].selectors;if(!selectors)
>   continue;for(var key in selectors){if(!selectors.hasOwnProperty(key))
>   continue;var hash=installId+"::"+key;if(initializedSelectors[hash])
>   continue;var
>   els=document.querySelectorAll(selectors[key]);if(els&&els.length>1){noteError({type:'init:too-many',option:key,selector:selectors[key],installId:installId});initializedSelectors[hash]=true;continue;}else
>   if(!els||!els.length){continue;}
>   initializedSelectors[hash]=true;els[0].setAttribute('cfapps-selector',selectors[key]);}}}
>   CloudflareApps.querySelector=function(selector){if(selector==='body'||selector==='head'){return
>   document[selector];} CloudflareApps.internal.markSelectors();var
>   els=document.querySelectorAll('[cfapps-selector="'+selector+'"]');if(!els||!els.length){noteError({type:'select:not-found:by-attribute',selector:selector});els=document.querySelectorAll(selector);if(!els||!els.length){noteError({type:'select:not-found:by-query',selector:selector});return
>   null;}else
>   if(els.length>1){noteError({type:'select:too-many:by-query',selector:selector});}
>   return els[0];}
>   if(els.length>1){noteError({type:'select:too-many:by-attribute',selector:selector});}
>   return els[0];}})();;(function(){var
>   prevEls={};CloudflareApps.createElement=function(options,prevEl){CloudflareApps.internal.markSelectors();try{if(prevEl&&prevEl.parentNode){var
>   replacedEl;if(prevEl.cfAppsElementId){replacedEl=prevEls[prevEl.cfAppsElementId];}
>   if(replacedEl){prevEl.parentNode.replaceChild(replacedEl,prevEl);delete
>   prevEls[prevEl.cfAppsElementId];}else{prevEl.parentNode.removeChild(prevEl);}}
>   var element=document.createElement('cloudflare-app');var
>   container;try{container=CloudflareApps.querySelector(options.selector);}catch(e){}
>   if(!container){return element;}
>   if(!container.parentNode&&(options.method=="after"||options.method=="before"||options.method=="replace")){return element;} if(container==document.body){if(options.method=="after")
>   options.method="append";else if(options.method=="before")
>   options.method="prepend";}
>   switch(options.method){case"prepend":if(container.firstChild){container.insertBefore(element,container.firstChild);break;}
>   case"append":container.appendChild(element);break;case"after":if(container.nextSibling){container.parentNode.insertBefore(element,container.nextSibling);}else{container.parentNode.appendChild(element);}
>   break;case"before":container.parentNode.insertBefore(element,container);break;case"replace":try{id=element.cfAppsElementId=Math.random().toString(36);prevEls[id]=container;}catch(e){}
>   container.parentNode.replaceChild(element,container);} return
>   element;}catch(e){if(typeof console!=="undefined"&&typeof
>   console.error!=="undefined"){console.error("Error creating Cloudflare
>   Apps
>   element",e);}}}})();;(function(){CloudflareApps.matchPage=function(patterns){if(!patterns||!patterns.length){return
>   true;}
>   if(window.CloudflareApps&&CloudflareApps.proxy&&CloudflareApps.proxy.originalURL){var
>   url=CloudflareApps.proxy.originalURL.parsed;var
>   loc=url.host+url.path;}else{var
>   loc=document.location.host+document.location.pathname;} for(var
>   i=0;i

Just wondering if it is possible to remove the rendered block of javascript or not.

Your comments are welcome.

Comment: The provided url does not work (in the Netherlands). I am using Cloudflare myself and i don't get any javascript inserted on my pages. Can you please provide some info on your setup?

Comment: go to `Page Rules` tab in CF and define rule that will ignore some conditions. see screenshot: http://joxi.ru/p27ggKUoBQ6E27 after adding rule clear CF cache

Comment: @num8er I tried with same result, I also checked a lot of web, found that render block javascript is vey popular, maybe I have to give up focusing on this

Comment: @arachide unfortunately have no idea how to help. What about putting copy of necessary js files to AWS S3 or to somewhere outside of hostname?

Comment: even facebook amazon have the similiar render block javascript codes, I will solve the more important problem, this one will be set to later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have installed one or more Cloudflare Apps. The JavaScript you see is related to apps. If you "uninstall" all apps, it should go away.